# How to fix 'Unresolved reference: HttpClient' with ktor-client-core targeting linuxX64

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to build a Kotlin Multiplatform command line application targeting linuxX64 in a first step. Therefore I wanted to build a client based on Ktor which is used in the common module.

#### Here my fairly simple setup:

**Version overview**

- Ktor 1.1.5
- Kotlin Multiplatform 1.3.31
- Gradle 5.3.1

**build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.31"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor") }
}

kotlin {
    linuxX64("linux") {
        binaries {
            executable()
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
                api("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.1.5")
            }
        }

        val linuxMain by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            dependencies {
                api("io.ktor:ktor-client-curl:1.1.5")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**src/linuxMain/kotlin/Main.kt**

```
fun main(){
    val client = MyClient()
    client.execute()
}
```

**src/commonMain/kotlin/MyClient.kt**

```
import io.ktor.client.*

class MyClient {

    private val client = HttpClient()

    fun execute() {
        //do something with Ktor client
    }
}
```

When I build the project I get the following build issue:

```
11:15:21: Executing task 'build'...


> Configure project :
Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an experimental feature.

> Task :wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

> Configure project :
Kotlin Multiplatform Projects are an experimental feature.

> Task :compileKotlinLinux FAILED
e: .../src/commonMain/kotlin/MyClient.kt: (1, 8): Unresolved reference: io
e: .../src/commonMain/kotlin/MyClient.kt: (5, 26): Unresolved reference: HttpClient
```

I'm new to Kotlin Native/Mutliplatform and Ktor. So bear with me if this my setup is wrong...

Comment: Adding `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` to settings.gradle.kts fixed the build issue. I just made a successfull HTTP Call with linuxX64 binary using ktor-curl-client :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` to **settings.gradle.kts** fixed the build issue. 
I just made a successful HTTP call with a linuxX64 binary using ktor-client-curl :-)

Comment: Seems outdated: Exception is:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no feature named GRADLE_METADATA

Comment: I got the same error.  Either my build is different or this is no longer a working solution.