# Adding Ktor To Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile results in Unresolved reference: HttpClient

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ktor, kmm

I can't get Ktor to work in a KMM project, I just get a `Unresolved reference: HttpClient` error when trying to reference any Ktor classes. If I try to manually add the ktor import it says `Unresolved reference io`. Other dependencies like `Kermit` resolve fine, it seems to just be Ktor with the issue. Here's my simple steps to reproduce:

[image]

1. In Android Studio (I have tried both 4.1.3 and 4.2 Beta 6), I go File -> New -> KMM Application.
2. In the shared module build.gradle.kts I add the dependencies for the ktor client:

```
val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.5.2")
        }
     }
```

3. In the `Greeting` class in commonMain I try creating an HttpClient like it says in the Ktor documents https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/use-ktor-for-networking.html#select-an-engine:

```
class Greeting {
    val httpClient: HttpClient = HttpClient()

    fun greeting(): String {
        return "Hello, ${Platform().platform}!"
    }
}
```

I get the `Unresolved reference: HttpClient`. The ktor imports don't work.

Things I have tried:

1. Adding the Android and iOS client dependencies as well.
2. Adding enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA") to settings.gradle.kts as suggested here:
   [How to fix 'Unresolved reference: HttpClient' with ktor-client-core targeting linuxX64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089071/how-to-fix-unresolved-reference-httpclient-with-ktor-client-core-targeting-li)
3. Cleaning, syncing with gradle, invalidate cashes and restart, closing AS and re-opening, building the project.

I really have no idea why this doesn't work, it seems like it the simplest possible setup. Here's my build.gradle files and settings file (which were auto generated from new KMM project wizard)

**shared module build.gradle.kts**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
        binaries {
            framework {
                baseName = "shared"
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.5.2")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1")
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13")
            }
        }
        val iosMain by getting
        val iosTest by getting
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
    }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

Project **build.gradle.kts**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.10")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**settings.gradle.kts**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
}
rootProject.name = "core"


include(":androidApp")
include(":shared")
```

Comment: Did you add ktor to your build.gradle (:app) ?

Comment: @AmrahAziz yes, I mentioned that (it's not :app, it's :shared in this project) `In the shared module build.gradle.kts I add the dependencies for the ktor client:`

Comment: @odiggity https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details please check that page and find the recommended version of ktor for your current kotlin version. Somehow libraries conflict with each other.

Comment: If just have an unresolved reference error in the IDEA but your project compiles fine then it's most likely a bug in KMM plugin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630659/cannot-import-io-ktor-to-common-module-of-kmm-in-android-studio

Comment: I made sure I was on the recommended version and still no luck. Thanks anyways @AmrahAziz

Comment: Ah, ya that is the same issue you linked @AlekseiTirman. I filed a Jetbrains ticket here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45769?_ga=2.224009949.793157345.1616991069-1300447325.1616713435

Comment: did you add a ktor engine, such as CIO  ? You need an engine. If you don't specify which engine in the ctor args, the default one is used, but do you have any? https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913665/5222156

Basically updating `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin` from 1.4.10 to 1.4.31 in root `build.gradle.kts` fixed the issue for me.

This is how my `build.gradle.kts` file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0-beta06")
        classpath("com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:1.4.4")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, that seems to have fixed it. Thanks @madim